# How do I change the color (or theme) of a viewController from another?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uicolor

**Introduction** 
I have a 'settings' viewController and a mainViewController in my Xcode project. In the settings controller,whenever the user presses on a static cell, it should change the color of certain elements of the mainViewController. For some reason this isn't working for me. Would anyone mind telling me why?

**Code**

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    ViewController *viewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Main"];

    self.tableView.delegate = self;
    if (indexPath.section==0) {
    _checkedCell = indexPath.row;
    [self.tableView reloadData];
    }

    if ((indexPath.row == 0) && (indexPath.section==0)) {
        NSLog(@"Let there be gold");
        UIColor *gold = [UIColor colorWithRed:226.0f/255.0f
                                          green:202.0f/255.0f
                                           blue:162.0f/255.0f
                                          alpha:1.0f];
        UIColor *goldComp = [UIColor colorWithRed:255.0f/255.0f
                                          green:255.0f/255.0f
                                           blue:255.0f/255.0f
                                          alpha:1.0f];


        //testing one label
        viewController.changeZone.tintColor = gold;
        viewController.zoneTime.textColor = goldComp;


    }
    if ((indexPath.row == 1) && (indexPath.section==0)) {
        NSLog(@"Let there be silver");
        UIColor *silver = [UIColor colorWithRed:170.0f/255.0f
                                 green:170.0f/255.0f
                                  blue:170.0f/255.0f
                                 alpha:1.0f];
        UIColor *silverComp = [UIColor colorWithRed:255.0f/255.0f
                                          green:255.0f/255.0f
                                           blue:255.0f/255.0f
                                          alpha:1.0f];
        viewController.changeZone.tintColor = argentum;
        viewController.zoneTime.textColor = argentumComp;
    }
    if ((indexPath.row == 2) && (indexPath.section==0)) {
        NSLog(@"Let there be snow");
        UIColor *snow = [UIColor colorWithRed:255.0f/255.0f
                                 green:255.0f/255.0f
                                  blue:255.0f/255.0f
                                 alpha:1.0f];
        UIColor *snowComp = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
        viewController.changeZone.tintColor = album;
        viewController.zoneTime.textColor = albumComp;
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (indexPath.section==0) {
    if (_checkedCell == indexPath.row) {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    }
    else {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    }
    }
}
```

**Explanation** 
The above code is supposed to result in a different color change of labels in the mainViewController depending on the cell tapped. Whenever a cell is tapped, a checkmark appears.

**Notice** 
The log is appearing in the console, but nothing else happens to the mainViewController. Any suggestions? The mainViewController is in a pageViewController and the settingsViewController is in a NavigationController if that helps with anything. Thanks!

Comment: You are creating a new instance of `ViewController` instead of referencing the existing instance of `ViewController`.

Comment: @rmaddy How do I go about referencing an existing viewController? I tried the following 'ViewController *viewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Main"];' from another answer but that didn't work either. The mainViewController is in a pageViewController and the settingsViewController is in a NavigationController if that helps with anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you do not see the colors change in the main view controller is because you are modifying a new instance that is not in the navigation stack. You could replace your previous instance in the stack if you do not need to maintain any state from it. Or, another option would be to use the appearance API and modify the colors there.